# Streaming the zip file to the calling application using Vert.x

Tags: nio, vert.x

One Gateway application is going to send a GET request to my Vert.x application. For this request, I need to read a large zip file from Amazon S3 server which I am able to read in BufferedInputStream. I don't want to download this file but rather I need to send this stream data to the gateway application (NOT a downloadable file with application/zip content type but stream data or byte chunks) which it will further send to end application where this stream data will be downloaded as a zip file. So the sending the zip file in form of stream to the gateway application I need to achieve using Vert.x. Already gone through lot of documentation and blogs but everywhere it is given to download the zip file which is not my intention. Could anyone please suggest how I could achieve this streaming of zip file in http response of calling request using Vert.x? Do I need to use Java NIO? If yes, could you please put details? Sorry, but I have nothing to put here as part of code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to use `HttpServerResponse:setChunked`? you can open the file, and then on each chunk, write this chunk to your response and on the end handler, end the response.

Comment: Yes, I used setChanked method. I am using pipeTo method inside vertx.executeBlocking method. Is it the recommended way of using pipeTo?